# Jquery Is not working in a href tag?

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to add a toggle function for a href tag. And this code is working fine.

When clicking the link first, its changing the text to "Remove the library" text and the function is called. Likewise clicking the "Remove the Library", the text has been changed and the function is called.

But When reloading the page in the stage of "Remove the Library text", Default text is showing, but the function is working fine.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="example">Add to Library</a>
```

I have written this jquery inside the document.write() function.

```
var clicked = true;
 $("#example").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
if(clicked){
   var personal_lib_checked = $('#example').attr('class');
   add_to_function(personal_lib_checked, 'add');
   $(this).text('Remove from Library');
   clicked  = false;
 } else {
   var personal_lib_checked = $('#example').attr('class');
   add_to_function(personal_lib_checked, 'remove');
   $(this).text('Add to Library');
   clicked  = true;
   }  
});
```

How do I show the current displaying text, though the page is reloaded ?

**After using the localStorage, still facing the same problem**.

```
var clicked = true;
 $(".example").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
if(clicked){
   var personal_lib_checked = $('.example').attr('class');
   add_to_function(personal_lib_checked, 'add');
   localStorage.setItem("removefromlibrary", "Remove From Library");
   var removefromlibrary = localStorage.getItem("removefromlibrary");
   $(this).text(removefromlibrary);
   //checked only for this condition
   clicked  = false;
 } else {
   var personal_lib_checked = $('.example').attr('class');
   add_to_function(personal_lib_checked, 'remove');
   $(this).text('Add to Library');
   clicked  = true;
   }  
});
```

Please someone guide me to solve this thing?

Comment: This is standard behaviour. HTML is stateless, meaning that as soon as you load/reload a page any previous changes you made to it are lost and it is set back to its initial state. If you want to save settings between page loads you will need to store that data somewhere, then re-inject it in the page the next time it loads. To do that you could use sessionStorage or localStorage, a cookie, a server-side session object, or a server-side data store. It all depends on how long you want to hold the data for, and what technologies you have available.

Comment: Also, never ever use `document.write()`. Given your example I can't see a reason you even need it, either.

Comment: Ok Rory, I will use session storage or localstorage to store the content. Thanks for your information

Comment: NB: You don't have `#example`, but `.example`.

Comment: ok trincot, I will change it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am still facing the same issue

Comment: You only read the value out when the button is clicked. As I mentioned above, you also need to read it when the page loads to replace the previous state

Comment: btw what does **add_to_function** do?

Comment: It has some query, I will store the content id into the database @sharif.io

Comment: @logeshvaran would you please check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've got no explanation of why this occured but here's how you can make it and it'll work splendid.

```js
var added = false;

function setLibraryText(that) {
  var result;
  if(added == true) result = "Add to Library";
  else result = "Remove from Library";
  
  added = !added;
  $(that).text(result);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="return setLibraryText(this);" href="javascript:void(0);" class="example">Add to Library</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why do you exactly need this but this one will work. [Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/codebazz/s8p6h9th/26/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="example">Add to Library</a>
```

Js

```
var clicked = (localStorage.getItem("status")=="false")?localStorage.getItem("status"):"true";
var hrefText;
var add="Remove From Library";
var remove="Add to Library";
if(clicked=="true"){
  clicked=true; 
  hrefText=add;
}else{
  clicked=false
  hrefText=remove;
}
$(".example").text(hrefText);
console.log(clicked);

$(".example").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(clicked){
     clicked  = false;
     var personal_lib_checked = $(this).attr('class');
     //add_to_function(personal_lib_checked, 'add');
     localStorage.setItem("status", clicked);
     $(this).text(remove);
     //checked only for this condition
   } else {
     clicked  = true;
     var personal_lib_checked = $(this).attr('class');
     //add_to_function(personal_lib_checked, 'remove');
     localStorage.setItem("status", clicked);
     $(this).text(add);
   }  
});
```

Comment: I am still facing the same issue